# How can I resolve a Unicode error when using raster data?

Tags: python, raster

I am new to Python. I am trying to instantiate a grid from DEM data. Then I will try to create a flow direction map from raster data. But when I write the following line:

```
(grid = Grid.from_raster("C:\Users\ogun_\Masaüstü\DEM", data_name = 'dem')
```

I have got this error.

> (SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape)

When I try the `r` or `R` functions, they don't work for this code.  ​

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python allow "escape codes" which start with a `\`.  For example, `\n` is used, that signifies a new-line character.

In your case, you've specified `\U` as part of `\Users`.  Python is trying to interpret that as a raw Unicode value (which is what a `\U` escape code normally denotes).

You can solve this either with an escape for your `\` characters (which makes the string `"C:\\Users\\ogun_\\Masaüstü\\DEM"`) or with a "raw string" which doesn't do escape codes (which makes the string `r"C:\Users\ogun_\Masaüstü\DEM"`).

I suspect the latter might be what you mean by "r functions".  These are not functions, but rather are lexigraphic markers.  They're much lower-level than function and can be thought of as part of the quoting itself.  If you tried to call these as functions, that would've been why it didn't work.

You can read more about by marking a string as raw [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

**NOTE:** This also is different between Python 2 and 3.  In 2, strings aren't Unicode by default, so you don't experience this unless you ask for a unicode string.  In Python 3, strings are Unicode by default, so this happens unless you explicitly ask for bytes with a byte string.